# Getting MySQL JSON Array field to join on a table

Tags: mysql

I have a JSON Array field on table A, I want to read the relevant descriptions from another table B.
Example:
Table A,

| id | types |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | [C,B,T] |

Table B,

| type | description |
| --- | --- |
| C | Car |
| B | Bus |
| T | Train |

While reading data from table A, I want the result should be,

| id | types |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | [Car, Bus, Train] |

Can anyone help me with MySQL query to achieve this?

Comment: The end output would be on a web/app page? What MySQL version?

Comment: @FaNo_FN Query output should be like I mentioned above. MySQL Version: 8.0.23.

Comment: You mean that the `types` output will retain it's JSON array format right? What I'm curious is the end output and how it's going to be used. I mean, will it end up in a report?

Comment: @FaNo_FN Sorry, I couldn't understand your question. The intention is to display the actual description of the types on the UI. For that, if I write a query like "SELECT * FROM A", I will get [C, B, T]. This is not understandable in UI. So I want to map [C, B, T] to table B and read the description and return it.

Answer (score 1):

Try this one:

```
    CREATE TABLE `a` (
      `id` int DEFAULT NULL,
      `type` json DEFAULT NULL
    ) ENGINE=InnoDB;

    INSERT INTO `a` VALUES (
      1, '["C", "B", "T"]'
    );

    CREATE TABLE `b` (
      `type` varchar(8) DEFAULT NULL,
      `description` varchar(16) DEFAULT NULL
    ) ENGINE=InnoDB;

    INSERT INTO b VALUES 
      ("C", "Car"),
      ("B", "Bus"),
      ("T", "Train")  ;



    SELECT d.id, CONCAT('[', GROUP_CONCAT(b.description), ']') AS result FROM (
    SELECT id, `c`.`type`
    FROM a,
    JSON_TABLE(`type`, '$[*]'
    COLUMNS(
       `type` VARCHAR(32) PATH '$'))
    AS c) AS d INNER JOIN b ON (`d`.`type` = `b`.`type`);
```

Result:

```
    |  id  |   result |
    -------| ----------
    
    '1', '[Car,Bus,Train]'
```

Answer (score 0):

This query will return your output.

```
SELECT tb.id, concat('[', group_concat(tb.description), ']') FROM table_b tb
WHERE tb.type in (SELECT data_set.types FROM (select SUBSTRING(types, 1, 11) AS TYPES from table_a) AS data_set)
```